# Expected Fisher information isn't positive definite for truncated normal with heteroskedasticity

Tags: multilevel-analysis, likelihood, meta-analysis, fisher-information

This question is about having a non-positive-definite expected Fisher information in a normal model in which observations have different dispersions.

Consider this simple normal model:

$$Y_i \sim N(\mu, \tau^2 + \sigma^2_i)$$

where $\sigma^2_i$ is the known (not estimated) error variance for the $i^{th}$ observation. Such a model can arise in meta-analysis as the marginal distribution of a hierarchical structure; there, the $Y_i$ are studies' point estimates.

Now, I'm interested specifically in modeling only observations with $Y_i/\sigma_i < 1.96$. Call these truncated observations $Y_i^*$. That is:

$$Y_i^* \sim N_{<1.96*\sigma_i}(\mu, \tau^2 + \sigma^2_i)$$

where the subscript means this is a right-truncated normal (RTN) with an upper truncation threshold of 1.96 * $\sigma_i$. The joint likelihood is:

$$\mathcal{l} = \sum_i -\log \left( \sqrt{\sigma^2_i + \tau^2} \sqrt{2 \pi} \right) - 0.5 \left(\sigma^2_i + \tau^2\right)^{-1} (Y_i^* - \mu)^2 - \log \Phi(\tilde{c}_i)$$

where $\tilde{c}_i = \frac{1.96 * \sigma_i - \mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2_i + \tau^2}}$ (i.e., the marginally standardized truncation threshold for the $i^{th}$ observation) and $r = \frac{ \phi\left(\tilde{c}_i\right) }{ \Phi\left(\tilde{c}_i\right)}$ (i.e., the [inverse Mills ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio#Inverse_Mills_ratio)).

Parameterizing the joint likelihood in terms of $(\mu, \tau)$, I calculated the expected Fisher information for the sample as a sum of each observation's Fisher information (since they're not iid given the different $\sigma_i$). However, it turns out that **the expected Fisher information is not positive definite for all values of $(\mu, \tau)$ and vectors of $\sigma_i$.** I know that the observed Fisher information can, in general, be non-positive-definite, but the *expected* Fisher information?

To avoid mistakes when taking all those derivatives, I got them analytically from R and then replaced the terms $Y_i^* - \mu$ and $(Y_i^* - \mu)^2$ with their [expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution):

$$E[Y_i^* - \mu] = -r \sqrt{\sigma^2_i + \tau^2}$$
$$E[(Y_i^* - \mu)^2] = \left( \sigma^2_i + \tau^2 \right) \left( 1 - \tilde{c}_i r \right)$$

**My questions: How is it possible that the expected Fisher information isn't positive definite for this model? If this is not the correct way to express the Fisher information for this model, what is?**

#### Interesting and suggestive tidbits

- The expected Fisher information for an untruncated version of the same model does *not* exhibit this problem; it seems to always be positive definite.
- If one takes derivatives of the truncated likelihood with respect to the marginal standard deviation ($\sqrt{\sigma^2_i + \tau^2}$) rather than $\tau$, then the expected Fisher information once again is positive definite ([c.f. equivalent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156199/jeffreys-prior-for-normal-distribution-with-unknown-mean-and-variance)). But when the $\sigma_i$ differ across observations, of course that approach won't work for estimating $\tau$.

#### MWE in R

Here's an MWE in which I calculated the derivatives of the Fisher information numerically to avoid math mistakes and then modified those analytical expressions to turn them into expectations. I also checked the derivatives against Mathematica, so I'm quite confident they are correct. Then I demonstrate a simple case in which the Fisher information isn't positive definite.

```
library(truncnorm)
library(Deriv)
library(testthat)

# likelihood of right-truncated normal
# .yi ~ RTN_{> .crit*sei}(.mu, .tau^2 + .sei^2)
simple_lli = function(.yi,
                      .sei,
                      .mu,
                      .tau,  
                      .crit ) {
  
  Si = sqrt(.tau^2 + .sei^2)
  
  # standardized truncation threshold
  alphaU = (.crit*.sei - .mu)/Si
  
  -log( Si* sqrt(2*pi) ) - 0.5 * Si^(-2) * (.yi-.mu)^2 - log( pnorm(alphaU) )
}

# # show it agrees with dtruncnorm:
# mine = simple_lli(.y = c(0.2, -1),
#                   .sei = c(1, 0.5),
#                   .mu = 0.3,
#                   .tau = 0.1,
#                   .crit = 1.96)
# 
# expect_equal( log( dtruncnorm(x = c(0.2, -1),
#                               a = -Inf,
#                               b = 1.96*c(1, 0.5),
#                               mean = 0.3,
#                               sd = sqrt( 0.1^2 + c(1, 0.5)^2 ) ) ),
#               mine )


# take partial derivatives for Fisher info
# dl / dmu
get_D1_num = Deriv(simple_lli, ".mu")

# d^2 l / d mu^2
get_D11_num = Deriv(get_D1_num, ".mu")


# dl / d mu d tau
get_D12_num = Deriv(get_D1_num, ".tau")

# dl / d tau
get_D2_num = Deriv(simple_lli, ".tau")

# d^2l / d tau^2
get_D22_num = Deriv(get_D2_num, ".tau") 

# the body of each of these functions shows the analytical form of the derivative
get_D12_num

# Get expected Fisher information by replacing (.yi-.mu) and (.yi-mu)^2 terms 
# in the derivatives with their expectations.
# The expressions from Deriv() are otherwise not simplified at all to avoid 
introducing mistakes.

# The kmm, kms, and kss terms below are the expectations of the partial derivatives.
fisher_1 = function(mu, tau, k, sei, tcrit) {
  
  # this will be the TOTALS for all observations
  fishinfototal = matrix( 0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2 )
  
  # build a Fisher info matrix for each observation
  for (i in 1:k) {
    
    # for this observation
    fishinfo = matrix( NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 2 )
    
    # from body of R's get_D11_num above:
    e2 = sei[i]^2 + tau^2
    e3 = sqrt(e2)
    e5 = sei[i] * tcrit[i] - mu
    e6 = e5/e3
    e7 = dnorm(e6, 0, 1)
    e8 = pnorm(e6)
    kmm = -(1/e2 - (e5/(e2 * e8) + e7 * e3/(e8 * e3)^2) * e7/e3)
    
    # from body of R's get_D12_num:
    e2 = sei[i]^2 + tau^2
    e3 = sqrt(e2)
    e5 = sei[i] * tcrit[i] - mu
    # e6 is scaled critical value:
    e6 = e5/e3
    e7 = pnorm(e6)
    e8 = e2^2
    e9 = dnorm(e6, 0, 1)
    
    # replace .yi - .mu in derivative with its expectation:
    expectation1 = -sqrt(sei[i]^2 + tau^2) * e9/e7
    kms = -(tau * (((e7/e3 - e5 * e9/e2)/(e7 * e3)^2 - e5^2/(e8 *
                                                               e7 * e3)) * e9 + 2 * ((expectation1)/e8)))
    
    
    # from body of R's get_D22_num:
    e1 = tau^2
    e3 = sei[i]^2 + e1
    e5 = sei[i] * tcrit[i] - mu
    e6 = sqrt(e3)
    # e7 is scaled crit value:
    e7 = e5/e6
    e8 = pnorm(e7)
    e9 = dnorm(e7, 0, 1)
    e10 = e5 * e9
    e11 = e8 * e6
    e13 = e10/e11
    # replace this one with its expectation:
    # e15 = (.yi - .mu)^2/e3
    # expectation of (.yi - .mu)^2:
    expectation2 = (sei[i]^2 + tau^2)*(1 - e7 * e9/e8)
    e15 = expectation2^2/e3
    
    kss = (e13 + e15 - (e1 * (e5 * ((e8/e6 - e10/e3)/e11^2 -
                                      e5^2/(e3^2 * e8 * e6)) * e9 + 2 * ((e13 + 2 * e15 -
                                                                            1)/e3)) + 1))/e3
    
    
    fishinfo[1,1] = -kmm
    fishinfo[1,2] = -kms
    fishinfo[2,1] = -kms
    fishinfo[2,2] = -kss
    
    # add the new fisher info to the total one
    fishinfototal = fishinfototal + fishinfo
  }
  
  return(fishinfototal)
}

# a case where it's not positive definite
fish = fisher_1(mu = 0.5, 
                tau = 0.3,
                k = 1,
                sei = 0.3,
                tcrit = 1.96)
eigen(fish)

$values
[1]  4.844817 -1.504037

$vectors
[,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.7723908 -0.6351476
[2,]  0.6351476 -0.7723908
```

Comment: This really is a programming question, as J. Delaney points out, as the expected Fisher information is positive-definite by definition.

Comment: Your likelihood is strange: it should be summed only over the $Y_i$ within the truncation region.  How exactly does this truncation occur in your observations?  Moreover, since you need to estimate $\mu$ and $\tau,$ your likelihood won't be a differentiable function of them everywhere, calling into question the entire approach.

Comment: @J.Delaney  The issue isn't whether it's a valid distribution, but whether it makes any sense at all.  Since the parameters are to be estimated, *how do you know which are the truncated values?*  That requires understanding how the truncation occurs, which is unclear.  The question is written in a way that initially makes it seem the $Y_i$ are *all* the (untruncated) observations.

Comment: @whuber if you have samples generated from $Y_i \sim N(\mu, \tau^2 + \sigma^2_i)$ and then *some* process that throws out all the ones with $Y_i > 1.96\sigma_i$ (recall $\sigma_i$ are known), then the resulting distribution will be as described. I agree that the truncation process is not fully described in the question, but it's also not that far fetched. I'm assuming the author of the question specified his model correctly

Comment: @J.Delaney Ordinarily I give the benefit of the doubt to the OP, too, but we're looking for reasons why this approach failed.  Although a programming error has been suggested, that might not be the reason (or the only reason).

Comment: @whuber As long as the model is mathematically valid, which it is, the Fisher information must be positive definite. So I don't see other options

Comment: @J.Delaney That's not correct, because the pd property assumes the likelihood is second order differentiable in a neighborhood of the solution, which includes the assumption the solution is not on a boundary.  That's why I raised questions about differentiability.

Comment: @whuber in fact (contrary to my previous comment, apologies)  the likelihood *is* differentiable everywhere. the parameters $\mu,\tau$ themselves are not bounded

Comment: @J.Delaney Criteria (adjusted for likely typos) of the form $|(Y_i-\mu)/\sigma_i|\lt 1.96$ are algebraically equivalent to $Y_i-1.96\sigma_i \lt\mu\lt Y_i+1.96\sigma_i.$ Assuming the $\sigma_i$ truly are known, collectively these criteria force $\mu\in[\max_i(Y_i-1.96\sigma_i),\min_i(Y_i+1.96\sigma_i)].$  That looks like a bounded parameter space to me ;-).

Comment: @whuber the criterion is $Y_i/\sigma_i < 1.96$, not as you wrote. It doesn't depend on the unknown parameters. If it did you were right, but that's not the case.

Comment: @J.Delaney That's right: I believe there may be typos there, because I cannot see any relevance to the criterion as written.  I'm hoping the OP might be able to explain what that is intended to mean.

Comment: Thanks for the engagement. Responses: (1) I've clarified the notation (now $Y_i^*$) to indicate that indeed, only the observations falling in the truncation region are modelled. Hence, the likelihood is conditional on falling in the truncation region.

Comment: (2) @J.Delaney is correct that the truncation threshold is $Y_i < c * \sigma_i$, which does not include any parameters and so doesn't impose a bound on the parameter space. Additionally, we know which observations fall in the truncation region given this criterion.

Comment: (3) I certainly agree that this might be a programming questions rather than a statistics questions, but it's hard to tell at the outset: the issue could be one of statistical model specification or one of programming, and the question seemed like a better fit for this forum than SO.

Comment: Will read through @J.Delaney's Matlab implementation now to help diagnose (3). Thanks again, all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expected Fisher information is positive-definite by definition, so there must be some mistake in your code.

Here is exactly the same calculation using MATLAB's symbolic math toolbox, which produces a positive-definite matrix with the same inputs:

(it's enough to check the case $k=1$, since a sum of positive definite matrices is also positive definite)

```matlab
syms mu tau sigma_i Y
z = 1.96 ;
c_i = (z*sigma_i - mu)/sqrt(sigma_i^2 + tau^2) ;
r = normpdf(c_i) / normcdf(c_i) ;

%the likelihood
logl  = -log(sigma_i^2 + tau^2)/2  - (Y - mu)^2/(sigma_i^2 + tau^2)/2 - log( normcdf( c_i ) );

%Fisher matrix from second derivatives
I = -[diff(logl,'mu',2) , diff(logl,'mu','tau') ; 
      diff(logl,'mu','tau') , diff(logl,'tau',2)] ;

%subsitute Y and (Y-mu)^2 with their expectations
I(2,2) = subs( I(2,2), (Y-mu)^2 , (tau^2 + sigma_i^2)*(1 - c_i*r) ) ;  %I(2,2) has only quadratic term
I(1,2) = subs( I(1,2) , Y , mu - r*sqrt(tau^2  +sigma_i^2) ) ;         %I(1,2) has only linear term
I(2,1) = I(1,2) ;

%evaluate at some values
>> eval( subs(I , {'mu','tau','sigma_i'} , [0.5,0.3,0.3] ))

ans =

    2.2836   -3.1146
   -3.1146    5.0987

>> eig(ans)

ans =

    0.2733
    7.1091
```

Comment: Good lord. I feel ridiculous. Your Matlab implementation was very helpful in identifying an absurd bug that I assumed wasn't possible given the agreement between my R script in Mathematica, but that's all it was. Here I was thinking there was something deeply wrong with my model. Thanks, and I apologize for asking possibly the worst question in CV history. ;)